# Upload multiple files with One Button Click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

This element,

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadEventosCasal" runat="server" />
```

can upload one file by time(button click).

I'd like to know how can I upload multiple files(queueing) with one button click.
I can't use .net 4.5. I'd like something like this example: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/12/aspnet-upload-multiple-files-using.html To make it works, I made these changes:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script>$(function () {/* jquery.MultiFile.js code pasted here */});</script>

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadEventosCasal" CssClass:"multi" runat="server" />
```

But this changes is only to run. When I try to upload, It doesn't work. Here is the button event:

```
protected void ButtonInsMultipleUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpFileCollection fileCollection = Request.Files;
    List<byte[]> imgs = new List<byte[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile uploadfile = fileCollection[i];
        imgs.Add(new byte[uploadfile.InputStream.Length]);
        uploadfile.InputStream.Read(imgs[i], 0, imgs[i].Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Search [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp+file+upload+multiple+files&aq=0&oq=asp+file+upload+mult&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3j60j62.3303&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I've found 3 solutions. 2 didn't work (both using jquery) and the other is for .net 4.5

Comment: Then provide that in your question (with links).  More info, the better.

Comment: @JoãoPauloOliveiraFernandes So which version of the .net framework *are* you using?

Comment: i've tried this one: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/12/aspnet-upload-multiple-files-using.html

Comment: I made some changes:
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadEventosCasal" CssClass="multi" runat="server" /> and
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script>$(function () { /* jquery.MultiFile.js code }); </script>

Comment: Please post such changes in your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error. In the button click method I made this changes:

```
HttpFileCollection fileCollection = Request.Files;
List<byte[]> imgs = new List<byte[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile uploadfile = fileCollection[i];
    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[uploadfile.InputStream.Length];
    uploadfile.InputStream.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    if(imageBytes.Length > 0)
       imgs.Add(imageBytes);
}
```

Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head? I would look into something like [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/).

You can select multiple files and it supports chunking... Yes, you might need to do a little more than drop a control on the page but you'd have more control and a slicker experience.

Check the [examples](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php).

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET 4.5 FileUpload control supports uploading multiple files:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
```

Comment: yes, but I can't use 4.5.
 The server I'm using does not support.